# Firestore Collection Group Query

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using google Firestore and this is my structure:

- Student(*Coll*)

  - SchoolListStudent(*Doc*)

    - ID 1
    - ID 2
    - ID … (*Coll*)

      - ID Student 1 … (*Doc*)
      - ID Student 2 … (*Doc*)
      - ID Student 3 … (*Doc*)

        - **Student First Name** … (*Coll*)
        - **Student Last Name** … (*Coll*)
        - **Student Address** … (*Coll*)

I have already create indexes (Single field for SchoolListStudent / Student Address)

I have unsuccessfully tried to perform a Collection Group query like:

```
querySnapshot_student_list = db.collectionGroup('SchoolListStudent').where('address_mail', '==', 'xxxx.yyyy@zzzz.com');
```

Have you an idea to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Collection group queries require the name of a collection to query, not the name of a document.  It will not recursively search all documents in all nested subcollections.  You will likely have to change the structure of your data to perform the query you wan. It's not a good practice to create collections with unique names (like user IDs).

Comment: Sounds like an answer, Doug! 

Comment: 4 days have passed. Will it be helpful if I'll write you an answer?